# Django form AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django

I have a django model like this -

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE)
    distributor = models.ForeignKey(Distributor)
    second_party = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    route = models.ForeignKey(DistributionRoute)
    total_price = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.date + " " + " " +self.total_price
```

I have tried to create a form from the model like this -

```
class transactionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
         model = Transaction
         fields = ['date', 'type', 'distributor', 'second_party', 'route', 'total_price']
```

But i am constantly getting following error --

```
File "/home/itsd/sts/transaction/forms.py", line 5, in <module>
class transactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "/home/itsd/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 247, in __new__
opts.field_classes)
File "/home/itsd/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 133, in fields_for_model
opts = model._meta
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I am stuck here for hours. What are the reasons for such issue ?

Comment: What you show are the only contents inside `transactionForm`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a comma after `model = Transaction` in your real code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, there are no commas now. At first, i have tried to create a form with two models. So i used comma to separate model name. But i have removed it a while ago to see if the error is causing due to that. But error remains.

Comment: def __str__(self): here date time and total price is defferent type. can you try with converting both to string type.

Comment: Had a similar problem today. I had an errant comma after my return statement in the view.

Answer (score 0):

It's too late to answer this, but if someone ends up here. I want to share, I too faced the same problem. The issue sometime for this kind of error is a `comma` somewhere left unintentionally. And as a comma converts a python object to a tuple. This error occurs.

Suggestion in line:-

```
type = models.IntegerField(choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE)
```

Although `type` is not a [reserved keyword in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) but still using type keyword will allow `type() function` in the scope of this class, so it is not a good practice.